# How to print customized message in code to Teamcity build log in C#

Tags: c#, build, teamcity, logging

Recently  I need to print some special message in C# code to Teamcity build log when executing, Does anyone know how to do that?

like:

//dosomething

//print messages

hope in Teamcity build log can see these messages.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

If you want to some message to appear in `Team City` build log from lets say a test then just simply use

```
Console.WriteLine("")
```

Here's an example to unit test logging to TeamCity Log

```
 [SetUp]
 public void Init()
 {
        try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("with_fresh_db Init Before RefreshController.StartRefresh: Time: {0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssss}", DateTime.Now));
    ....
            }

  }
```

And here you can see the result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use [Service Messages](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-servMsgsServiceMessages), for example writing this string to the stdout `##teamcity[message text='Hello from TeamCity']` will cause `Hello from TeamCity` to appear in the build log.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using msbuild to compile a C# application, or executing a C# application via your build script?.

Alternatively you can relay messages from your msbuild scripts using [this](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD4/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity).

Comment: yes, I know the way using msbuild to print message, but in my scenario, I need to run the program in mulitiple thread, I want to print the state of  any thread, so I want to do it in code.

Answer (score 0):

Inherit from Task and use Microsoft.Build.Utilities:

```
Log.LogMessage(MessageImportance.High, "Bla-bla-bla");
```

or

```
Log.LogMessage("Test!");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble getting Console.WriteLine to write to the build log from an NUnit test.

I assume NUnit or TeamCity redirects the Console stream so any calls from the system under test don't get logged and mess up the build log.

I redirected temporarily back to std out from my test method and it appeared in the log.

```
// redirect to stdio
var tw = Console.Out;
var sw = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput());
sw.AutoFlush = true;
Console.SetOut(sw);

// write 
Console.WriteLine($"Console writeline from test");

// put it back
Console.SetOut(tw);
```